# What is the T-SQL syntax to associate a specific number to a particular Month?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table called "DateDimension", which contains all the dates from 01 January 2001 till 31 December 2020.

I will need to use the contents of this table (extract shown below) in my Power Pivot model.

```
Day    Month     Year            Date
1        7       2016     7/1/2016 12.00.00 AM
```

My SQL query stands as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM DateDimension
```

I need to add a new column (let's call it "Sorting") in the output of the query that will do the following:

IF MONTH = 1, THEN VALUE = 7

IF MONTH = 2, THEN VALUE = 8

...

IF MONTH = 12, THEN VALUE = 6

To simplify, I am associating the values 1 to 12 to my fiscal year which starts in July and ends in June. That is, July gets value 1, August gets 2....and June gets 12.

How do I add this logic to my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a month value as an integer, this seems to just be `((month+5)%12)+1`.

Comment: Fantastic Solution! Thanks Damien!

Answer (score 1):

With dimension tables, it's common to add a column or columns to represent this right in the table. So, you would do something like:

```
alter table dbo.DateDimension add FiscalMonth tinyint;
alter table dbo.DateDimension add FiscalYear smallint;
```

, populate it accordingly, and change any code that cares about fiscal period to reference the information in dbo.DateDimension. Then if (when!) your company changes the definition of you only need to update the data and the code should magically do the right thing.

Moreover, with the code-only approach, you only have one notion of a fiscal year. This is important in the case when the definition of the fiscal year changes. Right now, it's July to June. But let's say they switch it to September to August. When you determine fiscal year and month with code, it will look like it's always been that way (or, you need to hack and do a case statement). With the data driven approach I detail above, it's all in the data and you don't need to change any code and you get an accurate accounting of both the past and future.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can achieve It with `DATEADD` in following:

```
declare @date datetime = '2016-12-01 02:01:01'

select month(dateadd(mm,6,@date)) as [Month]
```

Or if you want to achieve It with SSRS expression you can use `SWITCH` in following:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Month.Value = 1, 7,
        Fields!Month.Value = 2, 8,
        Fields!Month.Value = 3, 9,
        and so on...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
DECLARE @month INT = 12

SELECT Isnull(NULLIF(CASE
                       WHEN @month < 6 THEN @month + 6
                       ELSE @month - 6
                     END, 0), 6)
```